# Java UserNotFoundException what to do for the symbol

Tags: java, exception, netbeans

i'm writing the code for a UserNotFoundException,

```
public class UserNotFoundException extends java.lang.Exception {
    private String username;

    public UserNotFoundException(String username) {
        super("The user with username" + username+ "was not found");

    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public String[] getAvailableNames() {       
        String[] unames = new String[Member.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Member.length; i++) {
            unames[i] = members[i].getUsername();
        }
        return unames;
    }

}
```

The problem i have is in: `unames[i] = members[i].getUsername();`
They say `"cannot find symbol members"`. However when i try to create a new class called members or initiate a string it still doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well what is `members`? You haven't declared it anywhere in the code you've provided... what do you expect it to be? And what is `Member`? You can't just start using variables without declaring them anywhere...

Comment: "Member" is the name of the class where i wanna throw the exception. As for "members",when i initialize it as a string, it says i can read from it but not write in it. The complete code is still long, this is just one class where i have a problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not declare `members` at all. It could be a parameter of `getAvailableNames` method:

```
public String[] getAvailableNames(User[] members) ....
```